# Pegar valores selecionados de um combobox e mostrar em uma div

Tags: javascript

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário ao preencher, aparece automaticamente em uma div, conforme ocorre aqui no site. Em campo texto consigo pegar normalmente, mas como eu faria para pegar de um combobox?

Vejam abaixo o código do campo texto que comecei a fazer, mas preciso para o combobox:

**HTML**

```
<input name="Nome" id="nome" type="text" class="md-form-control responsavel required">

<!-- Aqui mostra o que foi digitado no campo acima -->
<p id="paragrafonome"></p>
```

O combobox que preciso pegar é esse:

```
<select name="Estado" id="estado">
  <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
  <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
  <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
</select>
<p id="paragrafoestado"></p>
```

**JQuery**

```
  // campo texto
  var nome = document.querySelector('#nome');
  var paragrafoNome = document.querySelector('#paragrafonome');
  nome.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  paragrafoNome.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><h3>" + nome.value + "</h3></div>";
  });

// Combobox
var estado = document.querySelector('#estado');
  var paragrafoEstado = document.querySelector('#paragrafoestado');
  estado.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  paragrafoEstado.innerHTML = "<div align='left' style='padding: 10px'><h3>" + estado.value + "</h3></div>";
  });
```

Comment: A pergunta está marcada com a tag `jquery` mas tu não está usando jquery em lugar nenhum. Tu espera uma resposta com jQuery ou sem?

Comment: isso está bem confuso, você menciona *combobox*, mas seu exemplo está ouvindo o *keyup* do e um *input* tipo text.. não deveria ser um select???

Comment: realmente está bastante confuso. De onde os dados estão vindo? Em qual formato?

Comment: Tem razão. Desculpem. Ajustei o meu post, vejam se ficou melhor?

Comment: Olá fernando. Tem Jquery conforme o exemplo citado.

Comment: Me desculpe a ignorância, mas li 3x teu código e vi apenas Javascript puro.. sem jQuery

Comment: Verdade Fernando. É javascript. Corrigi a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu pode ouvir o evento `change` do `<select>` e pegar a propriedade `value`.

Ex.:

```
meu_combo.addEventListener('change', function () {
    console.log(this.value);  // retorna o value do option selecionado
});
```

Porém esse código não cumpre com o objetivo quando o `select` tiver o atributo `multiple`. Para resolver isso basta acessar a propriedade [`HTMLSelectElement.selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) que contém uma [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) com todos `options` selecionados.

Exemplo:

```
combo.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var i=0,
        l = select.selectedOptions.length,
        values = [];

    for (; i < l ; i++) {
       values.push(select.selectedOptions[i].value);
    }

    console.log(values.join(', '));
});
```

Snippet com o código funcionando:

```js
var combo = document.getElementById('combo');
var valores = document.getElementById('valores');

var combo_multiple = document.getElementById('combo_multiple');
var valores_multiple = document.getElementById('valores_multiple');

function getSelectedValues(select){
    var i=0,
        l = select.selectedOptions.length,
        values = [];
        
    for (; i < l ; i++) {
       values.push(select.selectedOptions[i].value);
    }
    
    return values.join(', ');
}

combo.addEventListener('change', function () {
    valores.innerHTML = getSelectedValues(this);
});

combo_multiple.addEventListener('change', function () {
    valores_multiple.innerHTML = getSelectedValues(this);
});
```

```html
<select id="combo">
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
   <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<select id="combo_multiple" multiple>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
   <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>


<hr>

<strong>select:</strong>
<span id="valores"></span>
<br>
<strong>select[multiple]:</strong>
<span id="valores_multiple"></span>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado fernando e me desculpe as falhas no meu post, pois estava maior correria aqui ;)

Comment: Não tem problema, é mais para não criar resposta sem sentido mesmo.